# how to add zero to phone number in mask using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a 0 for my phone number mask. I want user to see 0 and then type the rest of their telephone number. How can I do this with jQuery?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
   $("#phoneNumber").mask("9(999) 999-9999");
});
```

User needs to see 0 at first and can't remove it.
For example, it has to be like `0(555) 555-5555`. 0 already needs to be in there when user types the phone number.

Comment: What do you mean by "see 0 and then..." Do you mean a placeholder? If so, use the placeholder attribute in the input.

Comment: It has to be like 0(555) 555-5555. 0 already needs to be in there when user types the phone number. @mykaf

Comment: hardcode value 0 in the field, and allow adding numbers right afterwards

Comment: @Raphael how can I do this ? I'm also using placeholder

Comment: `<input value="0" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the workaround below

```
'translation': {
    0: null
}
```

The idea is that you remove default behavior `'0': {pattern: /\d/}` specified in plugin (you can reassign this pattern to any other number or letter if you need)

After this, `mask` plugin just insert leading `0` if that missed.

```js
$(function() {
  // 'Basic Usage Examples'
  $('.phone').mask('0 (999) 999-9999', {
    'translation': {
      0: null
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="col">
    <label>Phone</label>
    <input type="text" class="phone" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: took liberty to make it `$(function() {` which is the recommended form.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have an input and have a number 0 in it and you want that the user can't remove the 0 you can do something like this:

```js
$('#phoneNumber').on('keydown', function(key) {
  if (key.which == 8 && $(this).val().length === 1) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="phoneNumber" value="0" />
```

<strike>Couldn't test it but</strike> You can just don't let him remove the first entry of the input field with an hardcoded value in html which is the 0 you want to stand first. You need to enhance this by don't let him type before the 0 and you need to disable copy & paste for example. The 8 after key.which stands for the current pressed key integer value. Which is 8 on pressing backspace.

Comment: added snippet as test - does not seem to work perhaps?

Comment: Now it works its not .value it .val().

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#phone').mask('N(999) 999-9999', {
        placeholder: '0(XXX) XXX-XXXX',
        translation: {
            'N': {
                pattern: /[0]/,
                optional: false
            }
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="phone">
```

Comment: I hope the code will be helpful to you. 

Comment: Could you clarify what's wrong with the code? I am able to help you more.

Comment: I'm curious as to why it was given a poor rating.